'IndexFlatL2' object has no attribute 'as_retriever'
I want to create a conversational retrieval chain. for that I try this block of code,
def get_conversation_chain(vector_store):
    llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/flan-t5-xxl", model_kwargs={"temperature":0.5, "max_length":512})
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history",return_message=True)
    conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever = vector_store.as_retriever(),
        memory=memory
    )
    return conversation_chain

but, I got this error : 'IndexFlatL2' object has no attribute 'as_retriever'
I wanted to create a chat-bot. user can ask question and bot will give answers according to the vector store.
